# Create Gitblit proposal ticket using git subtree

Tags: git-subtree, gitblit

I have a project `ProjectA` that uses shared library `LibB`. `LibB` is added to `ProjectA` using git subtree:

```
git remote add rm_LibB  ssh://user@127.0.0.1:222/LibB.git
git subtree add --prefix=libs/LibB --squash rm_LibB/master
```

According to this [documentation](https://dev.gitblit.com/blob/gitblit.git/refs!tickets!01!1!6/src!site!tickets_using.mkd) to create a proposal ticket you should do:

```
git checkout -b mytopic
...add a single commit...
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/new
```

However in case of subtree I'm usually using:

```
git subtree push --prefix=libs/LibB rm_LibB master
```

if I want to push changes made in `LibB`(being in `ProjectA`) to a master branch on remote LibB reposioty.

So far I've tried to

`git subtree push --prefix=libs/LibB rm_LibB refs/for/new`

which results in creating a new branch `refs/for/new` on remote LibB repository with no ticket created.

My current solution is to create proposal ticket from web interface and then

`git subtree push --prefix=libs/LibB rm_LibB ticket/N`

where N is the ticket ID.

But I would like to be able to create proposal tickets automatically.